# import excel file error

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, import-from-excel

I found a video on youtube that shows how to import an excel file to a datagridview. I'm getting an error: Could not find installable ISAM.

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Pricing2.xlsx" + @";Exended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
        (
            "SELECT PartNumber,ShortDescription,RetailPrice,JobberPrice,BasePrice,YourDiscount,YourPrice,LongDescription FROM [Pricing$]",conn
        );
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your connection string:

```
Exended Properties=
```

Should be:

```
Extended Properties=
```

Also I would recommend you a slight improvement of your code which consist in properly disposing disposable resources:

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Pricing2.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PartNumber,ShortDescription,RetailPrice,JobberPrice,BasePrice,YourDiscount,YourPrice,LongDescription FROM [Pricing$]";
    using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience. Only excel 97-2003 works.

CODE IN VB!

```
Private Sub DodajExcel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DodajExcel.Click
OpenFileDialog2.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
If OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim XLSPathx As String = OpenFileDialog2.FileName
End If

Dim connectionStringTemplate As String = _
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + _
"Data Source={0};" + _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""
Dim XLSPath As String = OpenFileDialog2.FileName
Dim connectionString As String = String.Format(connectionStringTemplate, XLSPath)
Dim sqlSelect As String = "SELECT * FROM [Arkusz1$];"
' Load the Excel worksheet into a DataTable
Dim workbook As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim excelAdapter As System.Data.Common.DataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSelect, connectionString)
Try
    excelAdapter.Fill(workbook)
    Dim worksheet As DataTable = workbook.Tables(0)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = worksheet


Catch
   End Try
```

End Sub